# Smoothening Analog Input Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, adc

I made a Potentiometer testing device that reads the analog values from an MCP3008 ADC.

In order to hide the sporadic analog input fluctuations I am calculating the average of several measurements in a while loop with a function similar to the following:

```
def analog_average():
    analog1 = (mcp_analog)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    analog2 = (mcp_analog)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    analog3 = (mcp_analog)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    analog4 = (mcp_analog)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    analog5 = (mcp_analog)
    analog_average = ((analog1 + analog2 + analog3 + analog4 + analog5) / 5)
    print(analog_average)
```

mcp_analog is the value of the ADC's first analog input.

I am getting the results that I want. Is there, however, a cleaner-more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop and [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```py
from statistics import mean

def analog_average(N):
    measures = []
    for _ in range(N):
        measures.append(mcp_analog.value)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    return mean(measures)

print(analog_average(5))
```

This way you can easily change the amount of samples without having to add more and more lines of `sleep` and `analog` variables.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great. Sorry I didn't make this clear, mcp_analog is predefined in my code. It reads the value on the first analog input of the ADC.

Comment: So I am guessing it is supposed to be a function call? `mcp_analog()`? Otherwise you are just adding the same value again and again and the final average will simply be that same value... @qeiynn

Comment: It is defined as `mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, mcp_read)` and
`mcp_analog1 = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P0)`. Every reading is slightly different due to the flunctuating analog input.

Comment: Again, according to what you say, `mcp_analog` is just an `AnalogIn` object. Is this your class, or some library? Do you have a link for it? I am interested to seeing exactly what it is

Comment: Some more details. The code is running on an adafruit CircuitPython microcontroller. In order to get the readings from the MCP3008 ADC a library from adafruit needs to be imported (adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008). I have imported is as MCP. Now my previous comment should make more sense.

Comment: Yeah I'm still not sure how using simply `mcp_analog` works, but as long as it's working for you I'm happy ^_^ I just got curious

Comment: A link from the following library icluding examples that should clarify this. [mcp adafruit library](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/mcp3xxx/en/latest/examples.html). In those examples `chan` is used instead of mcp_analog. Thanks again for the help as well as the interest! :)

Comment: Ok I found it! Look at the first example in your link, I think you need to do `mcp_analog.value`. This is why it seemed weird to be. By just passing `mpc_analog` you keep adding the same `AnalogIn` object. But with accessing a specific attribute like `.value` it makes sense to be something more dynamic that changes inside that object. Mystery solved :D